# Bind setup issue with Reverse Zone file

Tags: dns, bind

I am setting up in-house dns for some websites
I have what I think to be mostly working scenario.
However, when I run

```
rvw@ns1:/var/lib/bind $ named-checkzone rvw-inc.com 192.168.0.rev
```

I get

```
dns_rdata_fromtext: 192.168.0.rev:6: near eol: unexpected end of input
```

Here is my 192.168.0.rev file:

```
192.168.0.in-addr.arpa  IN SOA  rvw-inc.com. (
    1263187356      ; serial
    10800           ; refresh
    3600            ; retry
    604800          ; expire
    38400)

NS      ns1.rvw-rev.com.
$ORIGIN 0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.
142                     PTR     rvw-inc.com.
```

Any ideas on what is causing the unexpected end of input at 38400) ?
Note: I have tried it with the last parenthesis on a new line as well, with the same results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You SOA record is wrong.

Here is one example, from Wikipedia:

```
@   IN SOA master.example.com. hostmaster.example.com. (
    2017030300 ; serial
    3600       ; refresh
    1800       ; retry
    604800     ; expire
    600 )      ; ttl
```

Note that "between" `SOA` and the `(` you have two tokens: first the MNAME (or primary nameserver of the zone), and then the RNAME, which is the email address of the maintainer of the zone (with the `@` replaced by a `.`).

If you fix your record as the following it should work:

```
0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.  IN SOA  ns1.rvw-inc.com. hostmaster.rvw-inc.com. (
    1263187356      ; serial
    10800           ; refresh
    3600            ; retry
    604800          ; expire
    38400)          ; ttl
```

Note well that your owner was wrong too, it should be `0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.` and not `192.168.0.in-addr.arpa`: you were missing the final dot AND you forgot to reverse the order of bytes in the IP address.

You can see examples by doing `dig` requests:

```
$ dig SOA -x 192.168.1.1 +noall +auth

; <<>> DiG 9.12.0 <<>> SOA -x 192.168.1.1 +noall +auth
;; global options: +cmd
168.192.in-addr.arpa.   0 IN SOA localhost. root.localhost. (
                1          ; serial
                604800     ; refresh (1 week)
                86400      ; retry (1 day)
                2419200    ; expire (4 weeks)
                86400      ; minimum (1 day)
                )
```

`dig` output records in the "zonefile" format so you can reuse them as is in your files.

Comment: Indeed!  Thank you.  I added both the reversed ip and the email address, just to be clear